# Is there a way to get the parent (hosting object) from the constructor of the other?

Tags: c#, reflection

Basically lets say I have a class A that has a member of class B. Is it possible using reflection to get the instance of A (if any) that is creating the instance of B from within the constructor in B?

```
class A
{
    private B b = new B();
}

class B
{
    public B()
    {
        // How could I get the instance of A (object), if any, that is creating me?
    }
}
```

Guys, my ultimate goal is to create a generic bindable property class that is able to locate its parent's PropertyChanged interface (if implemented) to automatically notify properties. Say I have a class called MyBindableProp that is used in classes that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. What I want is to hook to that automatically by declaring the property simply as MyBindableProp { get; set; }. If I can locate the hosting object I know how to do the rest. Passing that in the constructor is off the table.

Comment: offhand, you might be able to walk the callstack upwards?

Comment: Do you mean finding an object which _created_ `B` (as described in the code comment) or the object which _refers to_ `B` (as described in the title).

Comment: Ask yourself why you want to do this. It sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Using the call stack is not 100% reliable. Compiler optimizations may completely remove or alter the way the code is actually called (for example, by inlining method calls) for performance reasons. Sounds like a cause for different behavior between debug and release builds (It works on my machine!!!! :) )

Comment: Guys, my ultimate goal is to create a generic bindable property class that is able to locate its parent's `PropertyChanged` interface to automatically notify properties. Say I have a class called MyBindableProp<T> that is used in classes that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. What I want is to hook to that automatically by declaring the property simply as `MyBindableProp<int> { get; set; }`. If I can locate the hosting object I know how to do the rest.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have to use reflection? You could just pass the instance of `A` to `B`.

```
class A
{
    private B b;

    public A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }
}

class B
{
    private readonly A a;

    public B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm looking at your comment where you say "How could I get the instance of A (object), **if any**, that is creating me?" I'm guessing `B` isn't always created from `A` so you can expose another constructor on `B` that doesn't take any parameters:

```
class B
{
    private readonly A _a;

    public B() {}

    public B(A a) {
        _a = a;
    }
}
```

And then make sure `_a` was initialized before using it:

```
if (_a != null)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the b constructor getting an  instance of A `public B(A instance)
{this.AObject=instance;} private B b=new B(this)`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have:

```
class B
{
    private A myA;    

    public B(A yourA)
    {
        myA = yourA;
    }
}
```

And in some class you should have a

```
private B myB;

public void createB() {
    myB = new B(this);
}
```

and you would inherit classes from this one, so you can use `createB` which will call the parameterized constructor of B and you would not have to pass `this` all the time.